# Passing NSArray result from web service to a UITableViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsarray

Sorry if this is a repetitive question, but i can't seem to get my head around the logic.

As a learning experience I am using a web service to fill a uitableview. Basically my web service returns an array of arrays and I want this to be passed to my UItableviewcontroller. I have my web service in a seperate class and I am unsure how to pass the array.

What is generally the best practice here?

This is my WebService.m file:

```
#import "WebService.h"
#import "VaskerierTableViewController.h"

@implementation WebService

// Search the Laundrettes

-(void) searchLandrettes: (NSString*) SS {

        //create the service  
        SDZDevices2Api* service = [SDZDevices2Api service];
    service.logging = YES;

     // Returns NSMutableArray*.
    [service LocationFindSimple:self action:@selector(LocationFindSimpleHandler:) SearchString: SS Max: 25 BankId: [NSMutableArray array] BankName: [NSMutableArray array] Id: [NSMutableArray array] Name: [NSMutableArray array] Icon: [NSMutableArray array] Zip: [NSMutableArray array] Attributes: [NSMutableArray array]];

}

// Handle the response from LocationFindSimple.

 - (void) LocationFindSimpleHandler: (id) value {

     // Handle errors
     if([value isKindOfClass:[NSError class]]) {
             NSLog(@"%@", value);
         return;
     }

     // Handle faults
      if([value isKindOfClass:[SoapFault class]]) {
         NSLog(@"%@", value);
         return;
      }

      // Do something with the NSString* result
          NSArray* result = (NSArray*)value;
      NSLog(@"LocationFindSimple returned the string-value: %@", result);

          // Antal arrays i alt
          int arrayCount = [value count];
          NSLog(@"ArrayCont = %i", arrayCount);

     /*
      * Første array indeholder kun taksten "OK"
      * De efterfølgende synes at indeholde 6 elementer
      * Derfor opretter jeg 6 array, til det indhold, som jeg synes at kunne finde
      */

     if (arrayCount > 1) {

         // Blot til test
         NSLog(@"test = %@", [value objectAtIndex:1]);

         // Et array til hver type information, for hvert resultat
         NSArray *bankId = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[value objectAtIndex:1]];
         NSArray *bankName = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[value objectAtIndex:2]];
         NSArray *iId = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[value objectAtIndex:3]];
         NSArray *name = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[value objectAtIndex:4]];
         NSArray *icon = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[value objectAtIndex:5]];
         NSArray *zip = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[value objectAtIndex:6]];
         NSArray *attributes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[value objectAtIndex:7]];
    }
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use class function to get the returned array from WebserviceManager. Call the function in your viewdidLoad of view controller of your view.

Try to get below concept.
In your WebserviceManager class

> +(NSMutableArray *)getArrayFromWebservice { ........
>       return returnedArray; }

In viewdidLoad of your viewController call that function and relax your tableview.

Update 1:
Check "+" sign that mean this is class methods on objective C.So you can call it directly using class name.

e.g.

> self.list = [WebserviceManager getArrayFromWebservice];

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. I am not sure what you mean by "Use class function to get the returned array from WebserviceManager". I get the logic in writing a class method that returns the array. But I'm not sure how I can access it. Might just be a newbie misunderstanding here...

Comment: self.list = [WebserviceManager getArrayFromWebservice];